# Node.js grabbing refresh tokens once a session expires FIREBASE

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently fetching a token, once a user logs in via my express server using the firebase ADMIN SDK. I have been searching high and low for the solution to persist a user's session once it expires after an hour of being logged in.  Is there a way to fetch refresh tokens along with the initial token after a user logs in?  I also would like to note I do not have firebase initialized on my client.  I only have it initialized via the express server where I have my cloud functions.  The cloud function is as follows:

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  }

  const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user)

  if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors)

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then(data => {
      return data.user.getIdToken()
    })
    .then(token => {
      return res.json({ token })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      if (err.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .json({ general: "wrong credentials please try again" })
      }
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ general: "wrong credentials please try again" })
    })
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this on the server? You'll need to initialize the Firebase SDK client side to use the id token anyways, so why not just do the authentication step client side as well. then in future calls, have the user pass up their id token.

Comment: currently using it on my client side no issue

Comment: just storing it in local storage

Comment: The client should be managing the sign-in and resulting tokens. It doesn't make sense to do this on the backend.

Comment: If you perform the authentication client side, the SDK automatically handles caching and refreshing the token indefinitely. You can still send it up to your server whenever you like